# Project with path ':lib' could not be found in project ':xxx'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I am developing a Flutter package which will call to native android platform. I added a native module to android project. When I synced gradle file It was fine but when I added package to a Flutter example project, the project cannot build.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/user/project/xxx/xxx/android/build.gradle' line: 59

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':xxx'.
> Project with path ':lib' could not be found in project ':xxx'.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           1,578ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I also added

```
include(':lib')
project(':lib')
```

to package's settings.gradle
and added

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':lib')

}
```

to package's build.gradle

How can I add a native module to native specific platform when developing a Flutter package?